# Can I change Fill Factor option for our database server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, fill-factor

I have a production database for ERP which has clustered and non clustered indexes. Some other tables have index type as heap and  i don't understand what does heap means. Every month i have a job run this command `sp_msforeachtable "dbcc dbreindex('?')"`  to rebuild all indexes in our database  after that i checked the fragmentation and i found it to be still 98%. I searched on web to discover that our  Fill factor option for our server is 0, so can i change it to suitable percentage and what factors I need to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the documentation "[Fill factor 0 and 100 are actually interchangeable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15) and fill factor does not apply to heaps, which are tables without a clustered index.

[Brent Ozar has pretty good writeup on fillfactor settings](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/) which I recommend that you look at but it boils down to this:

Don't spend too much time on the exact fill factor unless you can pinpoint specific performance problems to page splits and then change those from the defaults, for instance indexes on `GUID` columns which are modified frequently

Use Ola Hallengrens [maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com) which rebuilds those indexes which are fragmented and skips the others making maintenance run faster and with less load on the server.

If your application uses quite a lot of heaps Ola's solution does not help rebuilding those. You can run `alter table <tablename> rebuild` to rebuild the heaps ( Alter Table rebuild command applies to SQL Server 2008 and above) but Tibor Karaszi has [more intelligent solution](https://karaszi.com/rebuild-all-fragmented-heaps) which you can run periodically.

Comment: I agree with Spörri's comments. Just a couple of other notes: Those that are 98% fragmented: are you looking at an index or a heap? As noted, rebuilding an index does nothing for a heap, since a heap isn't an index. And if it is an index, then you likely have very few pages, where fragmentation is unavoidable and irrelevant. And DBCC DBREINDEX is an ancient command. I agree that you should use a good maint solution (like Ola's). And, it might even be questionable where rebuilding index will buy you anything in the and, assuming you have some pretty modern storage.