# Can I modify the fill factor value while a database is in use?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL server 2008 R2.  I asked [a similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254244/can-i-change-fill-factor-option-for-our-database-server) before on this forum, now I'm asking:

- First, can I change the fill factor while the database is in use?
- Second, how can I determine the most suitable value for our server fill factor?  On what does this depend?

Answer (score 1):

"yes", you can change the fill factor while the database is in use... **If** you can accept the **blocking**! I've found that it is seldom a good idea to have it different that 0 (or 100).

The dbreindex will not work on your heaps, so you should create a clustered index instead. (see for instance this [Kimberly Tripps blog post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) or this https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/sp_blitzindex-self-loathing-indexes/ on "heaps with forwarded records"
You may also want to download sp_Bliz from https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/. This will help you investigate what may help your server run faster.

Comment: and that server is out of support. Get upgraded and use Query Store to see what the problem really is.